# How to use TabController

Tags: flutter, tabbar, flutter-appbar

I just learned flutter, I was confused how to use the TabController, I had followed what was described on the official website, but an error appeared, and I don't know how to fix it.

I just want to change the title and leading from the appbar when changing tabs.

```
final List<ChangeTitleAndLeading> _data = [
  new ChangeTitleAndLeading(title: "Home", leading: Icon(Icons.home)),
  new ChangeTitleAndLeading(title: "Profile", leading: Icon(Icons.person)),
  new ChangeTitleAndLeading(title: "Friends", leading: Icon(Icons.people))
];

ChangeTitleAndLeading _handler;
TabController _controller;

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();

  _checkEmailVerification();

  _controller = TabController(vsync: this, length: 3);
  _handler = _data[0];
  _controller.addListener(_handleSelected);
}

@override
void dispose() {
  _controller.dispose();
  super.dispose();
}

void _handleSelected() {
  setState(() {
    _handler = _data[_controller.index];
  });
}

return MaterialApp(
  theme: new ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: Colors.teal,
  ),
  home: new Scaffold(
    appBar: new AppBar(
      leading: Icon(Icons.home),
      title: new Text("Home"),
      bottom: new TabBar(
        controller: _controller,
        tabs: _tabs,
      ),
    ),

    body: TabBarView(
      controller: _controller,
      children: _pages,
    ),

    floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: () {
          print('Current Index: ${_handler.title}');
        }
    ),

class ChangeTitleAndLeading {
  final String title;
  final Widget leading;

  ChangeTitleAndLeading({
    @required this.title,
    @required this.leading
  }) :
    assert(title != null),
    assert(leading != null);
}
```

Error log:

> Error Log:
>       I/flutter (19638): No TabController for TabBarView.
>       I/flutter (19638): When creating a TabBarView, you must either provide an explicit TabController using the "controller"
>       I/flutter (19638): property or you must ensure that there is a DefaultTabController above the TabBarView.
>   I/flutter (19638): In this case, there was neither an explicit controller nor a default controller.
>       ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
>
> I/flutter (19638): Another exception was thrown: No TabController for TabBar.

And when i change this:
 `leading: Icon(Icons.home),` to `leading: _handler.leading,`
and this:
 `title: new Text("Home"),` to `title: new Text(_handler.title),`
always return error `_handler.leading` or `_handler.title` was null

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/upj7p.jpg)

Comment: it is better to add your code in text format

Comment: Okay, I will add it

Comment: done, please help

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The issue is that you are missing a tabbarcontroller

Your code should be:

```dart
return MaterialApp(
  theme: new ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: Colors.teal,
  ),
  home: DefaultTabController(
    length: 3,
    child: new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        leading: Icon(Icons.home),
        title: new Text("Home"),
        bottom: new TabBar(
          controller: _controller,
          tabs: _tabs,
        ),
      ),
      body: TabBarView(
        controller: _controller,
        children: _pages,
      )...
```

Comment: Thanks, now the ```the getter leading was called on null``` error on appbar ```leading: _handler.leading``` still not fixed

Comment: Have you tried initializing the variables? Build is called before initstate

Comment: Oke, i will try it, Thank you for the help

Answer (score 20):

**Try this solution :-**

don't forget to inhert

> TickerProviderStateMixin

[image]

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage();

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  late TabController tabController;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    tabController = TabController(
      initialIndex: 0,
      length: 2,
      vsync: this,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final theme = Theme.of(context);

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Row(
          children: [
            Image.asset(
              'assets/images/png/logo.png',
              height: 60,
              width: 60,
            ),
            Spacer(),
            Container(
              width: 400,
              child: TabBar(
                labelColor: Color.fromRGBO(4, 2, 46, 1),
                labelStyle: theme.textTheme.headline1,
                indicatorColor: Color.fromRGBO(4, 2, 46, 1),
                unselectedLabelColor: Colors.grey,
                controller: tabController,
                tabs: [
                  Text('الفاتورة'),
                  Text('دليفري'),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: TabBarView(
          controller: tabController,
          children: [
            Container(
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
            Container(
              color: Colors.orange,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    tabController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

Comment: This should work, but for some reason on the new flutter version "controller: tabController" throws "Invalid constant value". Still looking for a solution.

Comment: send me screenshot pls

Comment: @Dpedrinha Inside the AppBar, if you have created the TabBar as constnat then you would get the error as `invalid const error`